# ASPNET Core HttpPost [FromBody] parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning MVC and trying to follow the tutorial on PluralSight.  I try to follow exactly what the author has, but in the video he is able to add new stop while I cannot because the binding parameter in HttpPost method is always null.  I try to switch `[FromBody]` to `string` type, but still does not work.

```
public class StopViewModel
{
    [Required()]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    public DateTime Arrival { get; set; }
}
```

Client view layout:

```
 <form novalidate name="newStopForm" ng-submit="vm.addStop()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="arrival" name="arrival"
               ng-model="vm.newStop.arrival"
               required
               ng-pattern="/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/" />
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="newStopForm.arrival.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="newStopForm.arrival.$error.pattern">Must be in format of MM/DD/YYYY.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Location</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="loc" name="loc" ng-model="vm.newStop.loc" required ng-minlength="5" />
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="newStopForm.loc.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="newStopForm.loc.$error.minlength">Must be 5 characters or more</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="newStopForm.$invalid" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

This is where the null occurs.  "`[FromBoyd]StopViewModel vm`" and `vm` is always *null*.

```
[HttpPost("Api/Trips/{vacation}/stops")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewStop(string vacation, [FromBody]StopViewModel vm)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newStop = Mapper.Map<Stop>(vm);

            _vacationRepo.AddStop(vacation, User.Identity.Name, newStop);

            //now we add new stop to the database
            if (await _vacationRepo.AddToDbAsync())
            {
                return Created($"api/trips/{vacation}/stops/{newStop.Name}",
                    Mapper.Map<StopViewModel>(newStop));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var modelStateKey in ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
            {
                var modelStateVal = ViewData.ModelState[modelStateKey];
                foreach (var error in modelStateVal.Errors)
                {
                    var key = modelStateKey;
                    var errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
                    var exception = error.Exception;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        string info = err.Message;
    }

    return BadRequest("Post- Bad things happened");
}
```

Updated:
Adding JavaScript file.

```
    (function () {
    //getting the existing module
    angular.module("app-trips")
        .controller("tripsEditorController", tripsEditorController);

    function tripsEditorController($routeParams, $http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.tripName = $routeParams.tripName;
        vm.stops = [];
        vm.errorMessage = "Dummy Error";
        vm.newStop = [];

        var url = "/Api/Trips/" + vm.tripName + "/Stops";

        $http.get(url)
            //$http({ method: "GET", url: url })
            .then(function (response) {
                //success
                angular.copy(response.data, vm.stops);

                _showMap(vm.stops);
            }, function (error) {
                //failure
                vm.errorMessage = "Failed to load stops: " + error;
            });

        vm.addStop = function () {
            //vm.errorMessage = "inside addStop";
            $http.post(url, vm.newStop)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //success
                    //vm.stops.push(response.data);
                    angular.push(response.data);

                    _showMap(vm.stops);

                    vm.newStop = {};
                }, function (error) {
                    //failure
                    vm.errorMessage = "Failed to add new stop";
                });
        }
    }

    function _showMap(stops) {
        if (stops && stops.length > 0) {

            var mapStops = _.map(stops, function (item) {
                return {
                    lat: item.latitude,
                    long: item.longitude,
                    info: item.name
                };
            });

            //show map
            travelMap.createMap({
                stops: mapStops,
                selector: "#map",
                currentStop: 1,
                initialZoom: 3
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: You should also include the AngularJs code being used to POST the data. i.e. `addStop`.

Comment: Which course are you following? I find it a little odd that it’s a course on ASP.NET Core yet it also uses AngularJs. The code you’ve shown reminds me of a course from Shawn Wildermuth but he uses Angular (not AngularJs) so I’m curious.

Comment: Yes it's from Shawn Wildermuth course and he uses Angular.

Comment: I think your problem is `vm.newStop = [];` - it should be `vm.newStop = {};`.

Comment: I just change to the brace {} also update to [FromForm] parameter in AddNewStop().  Now the parameter "vm" is no longer null, but the Name property that binds to StopViewModel remains null so the ModelState if-statement is false.

Comment: If you want to push your code to e.g. Github, I’d be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin  Thank you for the offering.  But I think it is ok because this is for learning purpose so I will not be adding new stop via the website.  I will have to run the datebase update command and add directly to the DataSeeding implementation.  I will come back to visit the issue later as I play around some more.